# bada Programming - Store user input in database

Tags: database, user-input, bada

I am new to bada programming. May I know how to store user input in to database? Like get user input from editField/editArea from user and store it into database.

Thanks all in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

see and learn.Its difficult to teach whole process:
http://forums.badadev.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=602
http://developer.bada.com/documentation/docView.do?docID=D000000685&&rlWlfcp=duq&isReturn=Y